# Select random dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, random

Let's say I have 2 dictionaries:

```
pal1 = {1:"bli", 2:"bla", 3:"blub"}
pal2 = {1:"blib", 2:"blab", 3:"bleb"}
```

Now I want to randomly select one of the two for further usage. My thought was creating another dictionary and assign a number to each dictionary name like so:

```
palettes = {1:"pal1", 2:"pal2"}
```

now the random part:

```
r1 = random.randint(1,2)
used_palette = palettes[r1]
```

so now used_palette has the dict name I will choose for further usage as a string in it. But how do I actually access that dictionary? `var = used_palette[1]` won't work obviously.

Any suggestions or other ways of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: `palettes = {1:pal1, 2:pal2}` replace variable to object from object

Comment: Also you do not need to construct `palettes` dictionary at all - it can be just a list and `used_palette = random.choice([pal1, pal2])` will pick one of the dictionaries directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice
pal1 = {1:"bli", 2:"bla", 3:"blub"}
pal2 = {1:"blib", 2:"blab", 3:"bleb"}
choice([pal1, pal2])
```